# Regular Expression for filename

Tags: regex

how can I make a RegEx for remove everything from last underscore to .jpg extension in filenames?

E.g. I have

```
aosta_8b08e16ae42367d29cbf11bcf27f376a.jpg
aosta_madreperla_014cb17607a4fb23fcb94a8f26efb267.jpg
```

and need to change it to this

```
aosta.jpg
aosta_madreperla.jpg
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the matched ones or replaced with empty string

```
_[^_]*(?=\.)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/vN4zQ4/1)

Pattern explanation:

```
  _                        '_'

  [^_]*                    any character except: '_' (0 or more times)
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    \.                       '.'
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Read more about [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:**

```
^(.*)_[^.]*
```

**Replacement string:**

```
$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nM3rM5/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^(.*)_` Captures all  characters from the start upto the last `_` symbol(excluding underscore) and store it into group 1.
- `[^.]*` Matches any character but not of dot zero or more times.
- Finally all the matched characters are replaced by the chars inside group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this using this regex

```
/[^_]+.jpg$/
```

and replace with `.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Search - ^(\w+)\_[^.]+(.*)$
Replace- \1\2
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iF3kB3/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
_(?!.*?_).*?(?=\.)
```

Try this.Replace by ``.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/18

`_` matches the character _ literally

`(?!.*?_)` Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the a string containing `_`.

`(?=\.)` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the string ends when it has a `.` ahead of it.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to use regexp, use just `substr`  and `strpos`, it should be faster.

```
$str = array(
    'aosta_8b08e16ae42367d29cbf11bcf27f376a.jpg',       
    'aosta_madreperla_014cb17607a4fb23fcb94a8f26efb267.jpg'
);

foreach ($str as $s) {
    echo substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, '_')) . substr($s, -4);
    echo '<br>';
}
```